# using localforage with clojurescript for firefoxos

Tags: clojurescript, firefox-os, localforage

I'm using `[cljsjs/localforage "1.2.10-0"]`

When I do:

```
(.setItem (.localforage js/window) "mynumber" (clj->js {:number (.-value number)}))
```

I get this error in WebIDE console:

```
 TypeError: *TypeError: window.localforage is not a function*
```

If I test it in firefox browser, it says the same, whilst if I introduce in the console `window.localforage.setItem()` it works :|

BONUS: each time I compile with lein cljsbuild auto I get this:

```
*Upstream deps.cljs found on classpath. {:foreign-libs [{
  :file "cljsjs/localforage/development/localforage.inc.js", 
  :provides ["cljsjs.localforage"], 
  :file-min "cljsjs/localforage/production/localforage.min.inc.js"
}], 
:externs ["cljsjs/localForage/common/localforage.ext.js"]}
This is an EXPERIMENTAL FEATURE and is not guarenteed to remain 
stable in future versions.*
```

Comment: This question was caused by **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to *help* future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Comment: @mate64 i had a conceptual problem, it wasn't typographical. besides that, the question about foreign-libs remains in the dark without a clarification

Answer (score 1):

well, seems the correct calling manner is `(.-localforage js/window)` [note the dash]

```
(.setItem (.-localforage js/window) "mynumber" (clj->js {:number (.-value number)}))
```

so far so good :D